# iOS Swift Date Picker select next interval

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, intervals

I was wondering if there's a way to select the date of the time picker to the next interval not to the nearest: If it's 1:47, I want the picker to display 2:00 and not 1:45.. is there any attribute for the UIDatePicker to choose the next Interval?

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time
datePicker.minuteInterval = 15
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I've set 15 minutes interval and if it's 1:47, I want the picker to display 2:00 and not 1:45.. is there any attribute for the UIDatePicker to choose the next Interval, not the nearest? Sorry if I didn't make myself clear.

Comment: You should edit your question to include those details.

Comment: set the minimum date thats it, user wont be able to choose 1:45 if you have selected 1:47

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to add a target for your date picker for UIControlEvents `.valueChanged` and get the minute component from the selected date. To calculate the next hour quarter minute you can use the following formula `(x - x % 15 + 15) % 60`:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
    }
    @objc func datePickerValueChanged(datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
        if datePicker.date.minute % 15 != 0 {
            if datePicker.date.minute > 45 {
                datePicker.date += 60*60
            }
            datePicker.date = datePicker.date.nextHourQuarter
        } 
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Int {
    var nextHourQuarter: Int {
        return (self - self % 15 + 15) % 60
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Date {
    var hour: Int { return Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: self) }
    var minute: Int { return Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: self) }
    var nextHourQuarter: Date {
        return  Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: hour, minute: minute.nextHourQuarter, second: 0, of: self)!
    }
}
```

[Sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zzqjvakgmdlx6sd/Quarter%20Hour%20Picker.zip?dl=1)

Comment: Hi Leo, much appreciate your answer. Based on your proposal I've written a function which does exactly it what I mean:

8:03 -> picker date is 8:15; 8:23 -> picker date is 8:30; 8:38 -> picker date is 8:45; 8:46 -> picker date is 9:00...

I'm pretty new to swift, so I hope my function is correct, at least it works

Comment: @N.Beer I have posted a sample project so you can see test it. If there is something that you don't understand  please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The UIDatePicker class does not have the functionality. You can only lock the selector to allow certain values (e.g. if you set datePicker.minuteInterval = 15, the available selections would start from the initial time and go in 15 minute ticks).

You can implement this behaviour yourself by listening to the value changed notification and setting the time manually (preferably with an animation).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it hasn't been clear what I mean.
I've written this function which sets the picker time to the next interval.
I don't know if it's correct but it works:

- Date 8:03 -> picker date is 8:15
- Date 8:23 -> picker date is 8:30
- Date 8:38 -> picker date is 8:45
- Date 8:46 -> picker date is 9:00

viewDidLoad:

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time
datePicker.minuteInterval = 15
datePicker.date = setDatePickerTime(datePicker: datePicker)
```

Set DatePicker Time to next 15 min interval

```
func setDatePickerTime(datePicker: UIDatePicker) -> Date {
  let calendar = Calendar.current
  let currentHour = calendar.component(.hour, from: Date())
  let currentMinute = calendar.component(.minute, from: Date())

  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat =  "HH:mm"

  var pickerOutHour = ""
  var pickerOutMinute = ""

  if (currentMinute > 45 && currentMinute < 60){
      pickerOutMinute = "00"
      pickerOutHour = String((Int(currentHour) + 1) % 24)
  } else if (currentMinute > -1 && currentMinute < 16){
      pickerOutMinute = "15"
      pickerOutHour = String(currentHour)
  } else if (currentMinute > 15 && currentMinute < 31){
      pickerOutMinute = "30"
      pickerOutHour = String(currentHour)
  } else if (currentMinute > 30 && currentMinute < 46){
      pickerOutMinute = "45"
      pickerOutHour = String(currentHour)
  }

  let pickerOutDate = dateFormatter.date(from: pickerOutHour + ":" + pickerOutMinute)
  return pickerOutDate!
}
```